# Confusion over implementation of wait() operation for semaphore

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, operating-system

I am not able to understand the atomic operations in wait(). The wait() operation is implemented this way in many of the sources/books:

```
wait(S) {
  while S <= 0;
  S--;
}
```

If operations such as S--, S<=0, and signal op which is S++ are atomic. **Even then two threads might decrement S value.** And then the whole idea of using semaphore is lost.

I even found some support from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) which gives implementation of wait() as below, and says that if block including S-- is atomic. And to me it makes complete sense.

```
wait(S) {
    while true:
       [ if S<= 0:
            S--;
       ]
```

Any thoughts over first implementation of wait(). Am I missing some thing.

Comment: "The wait operation is implemented this way in many sources/books":  That's not true.  It's not implemented that way in sources, because it would be broken as you say.  In books it is *described*, not *implemented*, and may be described the way you indicate to help you understand it.  The description in Wikipedia is more accurate, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semaphore `S` apart from initialization can only be accessed through **signal** and **wait** operations.

> Even then two threads might decrement S value. And then the whole idea
>   of using semaphore is lost.

**No, it is not possible**. The only thing that is possible is that multiple threads can try to decrement the value of `S`.

Suppose multiple threads are waiting in the while loop. This means that `S` is `0`. As soon as **signal** is executed, `S` becomes `1` and the condition

```
while S <= 0
```

becomes false. And **only one thread** will successfully execute the `S--` statement. To quote the bible of operating system *Operating systems principles by Galvin,silberschatz and gagne*

> All the modifications to the integer value of the semaphore in the
>   wait() and signal() operations must be executed indivisibly. That is,
>   when one process modifies the semaphore value, no other process can
>   simultaneously  modify that same semaphore value. In addition, in the
>   case of wait(S), the testing of the integer value of S<=0, and its
>   possible modification S--, must also be executed without interruption.

Comment: I think I missed this line while reading, "In addition, in the case of wait(S), the testing of the integer value of S<=0, and its possible modification S--, must also be executed without interruption.".